# How to Properly Utilize req.params in Next.js API Route via App Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I'm working with Next.js and using Express to fetch data from the database. Although I can successfully trigger a GET request via Postman using Express, I'm unable to do so through the API folder in Next.js. I have attempted to use [searchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) as suggested by the Next.js documentation, but this method was unsuccessful. I then tried using params following a discussion I found [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47072), but this also did not solve the issue.

Here is the URL structure I am using: http://localhost:5001/api/get-update-history/6

And here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from '@/app/config/database';

export async function GET(request, { params }) {
  const { toId } = params
  try {

    const driverUpdates = await prisma.UpdateHistory.findMany({
        where: { toId: Number(toId) },
        select: {
            updatedAt: true,
            afterValues: true,
            beforeValues: true,
            updatedByTo: {
                select: {
                    name: true
                },
            },
            updatedByUser: {
                select: {
                    name: true,
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (driverUpdates && driverUpdates.length > 0) {
        const response = driverUpdates.map(update => ({
            updatedAt: update.updatedAt,
            beforeValues: JSON.parse(update?.beforeValues),
            afterValues: JSON.parse(update?.afterValues),
            updateByUserName: update?.updatedByUser?.name,
            updateByToName: update?.updatedByTo?.name

        }));
        return new NextResponse([JSON.stringify(response)]);
    } else {
        return NextResponse(`No updates for this driver`);
    }

} catch (e) {
    return NextResponse.error(`Error getting updates history: ${e}`);
}
```

}

Could someone advise me on how to modify my code to make the GET request work through the API folder in Next.js?